# How to add libusb in Microsoft Visual studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, libusb-1.0

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, how can I add the external library `libusb` to my project?

Answer (score 1):

libusb will contain a LIB file, DLL file and header file. You will need to include the libusb header file in your source project. Then under your project settings you should go to the Linker section and add the LIB file as a linked object. Then, just ensure your DLL is accessible to your executable when running or debugging.